# Почему нельзя создать экземпляр компонента в юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему нельзя сделать `RigidBody body = new RigidBody()`, вместо `GetComponent<RigidBody>`? Как это работает с точки зрения C#?

Comment: Есть подозрение что никто тут не ответит на сий вопрос..... проще всего - это покопаться в исходниках юнити, которые спкойно себе лежат на гитхабе. А также в принципе через IDE можно побродить по внутренностям.

Comment: `C#` тут не при чём, всё дело в основном в скорости самого движка `Unity`. Создание объектов программно - очень долгая процедура, плюс возни много с настройкой. Поэтому гораздо быстрее найти на заранее созданной сцене уже готовый объект. Собственно, в `Unity` даже те игровые объекты, которые вроде как умирают и появляются новые стараются не уничтожать и создавать заново, а просто скрывать, перенастраивать - и опять показывать. Это гораздо быстрее.

Comment: @CrazyElf вы говорите о пуле объектов (object pooling), такой механизм если в Unity и есть, то для совсем немногих компонент. Для `GameObject` его по умолчанию точно нет, но можно легко реализовать самостоятельно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можно ссылку на гит?

Comment: @Fitamas так в поиске вбить unity3d github и усё))  .... ну ладно... https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference

Comment: При необходимости можно создавать компонент сразу у нужного объекта: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компонент не может существовать сам по себе, он существует только в экосистеме `GameObject`та. `GameObject` его создает, апдейтит, отправляет калбеки типа `Start()` или `OnCollisionEnter()` и уничтожает.

Для добавления нового компонента используется `AddComponent<T>()`. Не все компоненты могут быть на `GameObject` в множественном количестве, можно добавить хоть 10 `AudioSorce`, но `RigidBody` может быть только один, из-за атрибута `[DisallowMultipleComponent]` во избежание противоречий того что объект имеет тело массой 10 подверженной гравитации и тело массой 100500 не подверженное гравитации одновременно. Некоторые компоненты не могут существовать без других как `FixedJoint` не может существовать без `RigidBody` из-за атрибута `[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]` и добавляется автоматически и удалить его будет не возможно пока на нем `FixedJoint` или другой компонент который в нем нуждается. За всем этим следит `GameObject`.

`MonoBehaviour`ы наследуют свойство `gameObject`, объект к которому он принадлежит. `GetComponent<T>()` это `gameObject.GetComponent<T>()`, как и `transfomr`, которой тоже компонент это `gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>()` (но уже кешированный). `MonoBehaviour` неразрывно связан с `GameObject`.